error NG8002: Can't bind to 'theme' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-skeleton-loader'
In our application with angular v15 we have installed the package "ngx-skeleton-loader" v8.0.0.
We cannot use the latest version of the package because we should update angular to v17.
From docs that component should have a property "[theme]" to custom the skeleton appearance.
When we add the property [theme] (example: <ngx-skeleton-loader [theme]="{ width: '100px' }">) we get this error: "error NG8002: Can't bind to 'theme' since it isn't a known property of 'ngx-skeleton-loader'".
Does anybody had the same problem? Any idea to fix this?
Thanks!
We tried to uninstall and re-install the package but nothing changed.
We tried to install the package in a complete new project but nothing changed.

please share the details of your project, if possible github repo!

This can happen if you forgot to import the module. Make sure to import the NgxSkeletonLoaderModule in your module like this
@NgModule({
imports: [
    NgxSkeletonLoaderModule
],
...

})
If you use standalone components you can probably import this directly in your component or with NgxSkeletonLoaderModule.forRoot()

Hi tobiso. Thanks for reply. We already imported it in our module. The package works great but can't use the "[theme]" property.

I just tried it in my Angular 16 Project, works like expected. Can you create a reproducer on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

I did the same on stackblitz and it works both with ngx-skeleton-loader v8.0.0 and latest version. I'm really not understanding what's wrong with my project.
Pressing F12 on Theme property i go into the library and the property exists but if I try to use it angular give me error.
